# Adding suffix/prefix into simple number counter script

Tags: jquery, html

So I'm displaying some stats on a page. It works nicely and it's very simple. I cannot seem to get a suffix or prefix to work, likely as I'm new to coding in general. Where would I add in % or £ $ so they display alongside the number

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), countTo = $this.attr('data-count');  
    $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
        countNum: countTo
        },
        {
            duration: 5000,
            easing:'linear',
            step: function() {
                $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
            },
            complete: function() {
            $this.text(this.countNum);
        }
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webstats_container">
    <div align="center" class="webstats">
        <h3><strong>Our Stats</strong></h3>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
       <span>Average Claim:</span>
    <div class="counter" data-count="100">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
       <span>Uphold Percentage:</span>
    <div class="counter" data-count="100">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
   <span>Total Claimed:</span>
    <div class="counter" data-count="100">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the suffix and prefix values when setting counter value to element

**For this you can just Change;**

```
$this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
```

and

```
 $this.text(this.countNum);
```

**to**

```
var suffix="";
var prefix="%";
$this.text(suffix+Math.floor(this.countNum)+ prefix);
```

and

```
$this.text(suffix+this.countNum + prefix );
```

```js
 var suffix="";
     var prefix="%";
    $('.counter').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    countTo = $this.attr('data-count');  
    $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
    },
    {
    duration: 5000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
    $this.text(suffix+Math.floor(this.countNum)+ prefix);
    },
    complete: function() {
    $this.text(suffix+this.countNum + prefix );
    }
    });  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="webstats_container">
    <div align="center" class="webstats">
    <h3><strong>Our Stats</strong></h3>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4">
   <span>Average Claim:</span>
    <div class="counter" data-count="100">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
   <span>Uphold Percentage:</span>
    <div class="counter" data-count="100">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
   <span>Total Claimed:</span>
    <div class="counter" data-count="100">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simple & easy solution within 10 mins. Thank you very much

Comment: @Niall welcome.thanks hope you will upvote this.this will help user to find good answer